# Minimum spanning tree using Kruskal in Python, recursion enters a infinite loop

Tags: python, tree, minimum

The purpose of this code is to create the shortest path that connect each point. I've tried to implement the Kruskals algorithm in Python, but there is a problem and it occurs when the function findSet(x) is called. It seems like the program enters a infinite loop. I've tried to print x, x.dad and x.dad.dad and x in the crucial moment returns the initial x. I really don't know where is the problem.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x = None, y = None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dad = None
        self.rank = None

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, firstPoint = None, secondPoint = None, value = None):
        self.firstPoint = firstPoint
        self.secondPoint = secondPoint
        if self.firstPoint != None and self.secondPoint != None:
            self.value = abs(firstPoint.x-secondPoint.x) + abs(firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y)
        else:
            self.value = float("inf")

def makeSet(node):
    node.dad = node
    node.rank = 0

def findSet(x):
    print x, x.dad,x.dad.dad
    if x == x.dad:
        return x
    x.dad = findSet(x.dad)
    return x.dad

def unionSet(node1,node2):
    root1 = findSet(node1)
    root2 = findSet(node2)
    if root1.rank < root2.rank:
        root1.dad = root2
    if root1.rank > root2.rank:
        root2.dad = root1
    else:
        root2.dad = root1
        root1.rank += 1


def merge(A, p, q, r):
    L = A[p:q+1]
    R = A[q+1:r+1]
    infinite = Edge()
    L.append(infinite)
    R.append(infinite)
    temp = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in range(p,r+1):
        if L[i].value <=  R[j].value:
            temp.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            temp.append(R[j])
            j += 1
    A[p:r+1] = temp

def mergeSort(A,p,r):
    A2 = A
    if p < r:
        q = int((p+r)/2)
        mergeSort(A2, p, q)
        mergeSort(A2, q+1, r)
        merge(A2, p, q, r)

def readPoint(A):
    temp = []
    for i in range(0,len(A), 2):
        tempPoint = Point(A[i],A[i+1])
        makeSet(tempPoint)
        temp.append(tempPoint)
    return temp

def calculateEdges(A):
    tempArray = []
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(A)):
            edge = Edge(A[i], A[j])
            tempArray.append(edge)
    return tempArray

def Kruskal(N, E):
    mergeSort(E,0,len(E)-1)
    j = 0
    i = 0
    total = 0
    while j < N:
        if findSet(E[i].firstPoint) != findSet(E[i].secondPoint):
            unionSet(E[i].firstPoint,E[i].secondPoint)
            j += 1
            total += E[i].value
        if i < len(E) - 1:
            i += 1
    return total


Ar = readPoint([18, 2, 99, 68])
E = calculateEdges(Ar)
print Kruskal(len(Ar),E)
```

Comment: At what point exactly does the code cease to behave as expected? Step through the code with a debugger for further insight.

Comment: The code enters the infinite loop in the findSet() function, I suppose that it enters it as soon as the node passed to the function is not is own dad, but has a dad.

Comment: So, and at what point does the node become invalid in that way which causes the endless loop?

Comment: I will try to debug it. By the way i've printed out the value of node, node.dad and node.dad.dad.
node.dad and node.dad.dad are always the same.
node and node.dad are the same one time and the other they are not.